# Setting buttons not visible when working with api level 8

Tags: android, settings, android-menu, android-2.0-eclair

[image]

The setting button is there when I am creating my project with min sdk version 14 or more but I need it to be 8 for android 2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need third party library actionbarsherlock below link for more details:

http://actionbarsherlock.com/

and it's support android 2.2 to higher all same gui's based on ics or honeycomb!

Answer (score 1):

The "setting button" is part of [ActionBar](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) design pattern introduced in Honeycomb (Android 3.0). If you want if for older devices, you can use [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) or ActionBarCompat (announced by Google at IO 2013 but still unreleased).